# Find the second last occurrence of a particular value in the column

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to find the row number of the second last instance for a particular value.

See example screenshot below:

[image]

The image has 4 values in the column and I am trying to find the second to last instance of a value say GR 3 which is in row 5. I need to find the second last row.
i.e row 3 however I tried using the below code.

```
Range("E:E").Find(what:="GR 3", after:=Range("E1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
```

The above code gives me either the last occurrence.
i.e row 5 and if I remove the search direction parameter it gives me only the first occurrence 
i.e row 2.

Comment: Searching with xlPrevious, assign the found cell to a variable and repeat the same search defining `After` as the cell where the value was first found by means of that variable.

Comment: i tried doing that however it always returns the last occurrence even if the active cell is the first. i need it to search only between the active cell and the first cell.

Answer (score 0):

if you filter that value ,you can use this :

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$7").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="GR 3"
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).row
```

it will select the second row in a filtered column value.

Comment: hi Ioana, thanks for the above but the above code will always return the second row. but the data might not always have just 3 occurrences it could have more. so in any instance i would want the row number for the second to last instance. thanks for trying but i figured out the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will loop through the range and will consider the range from the first cell up to the value of i. In the first "where" i am setting the value of the last occurrence of my desired value in "what". In the second "where" i am finding the previous occurrence of "what" based on the previous value of where which gives me the address of the my second last occurrence and finally the col variable saves the row number from the address stored in where.

```
Sub Find()

Dim where As Range
Dim col as Long

For i=2 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Set where = Range("E2:E" & i).Find(what:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value, after:=Range("E2"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

Set where = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E" & i).FindPrevious(where)

col = Mid(where.Address(0, 0), 2)

Next i

End Sub
```